# memory_order changes to default when passed by non-const lvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-barriers

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> val{1};

const auto my_order = std::memory_order_relaxed; // const lvalue

int main()
{
    val.store(42, my_order);
}
```

This code has no relevance, but I noticed something strange with regards to memory ordering. The compiler produces the following assembly for main (x86_64, g++ 6.2.1, compiled with -O3):

```
0x00000000004004c0 <+0>:     movl   $0x2a,0x200b5a(%rip)        # 0x601024 <val>
0x00000000004004ca <+10>:    xor    %eax,%eax
0x00000000004004cc <+12>:    retq
```

There are no special CPU instructions to deal with atomic which is expected on x86 with `std::memory_order_relaxed` ordering.
However, when the `const` qualifier is removed from `my_order`

```
auto my_order = std::memory_order_relaxed; // non-const lvalue
```

the compiler generated assembly becomes:

```
0x00000000004004c0 <+0>:     movl   $0x2a,0x200b5a(%rip)        # 0x601024 <val>
0x00000000004004ca <+10>:    xor    %eax,%eax
0x00000000004004cc <+12>:    mfence
0x00000000004004cf <+15>:    retq
```

The `mfence` instruction seems to indicate that `std::memory_order_seq_cst` ordering is now used (the default). This is kind of surprising to me. Even though `my_order` is an lvalue (unconventional to specify memory ordering), it is passed by value (still `std::memory_order_relaxed`) and I don't see how non-`const` would change the result. I could not find a particular overload in the library header files for this.
With clang I see similar results, except that it uses `xchg`, which is the clang way of expressing sequential consistency.
What could explain the difference ?

Comment: I think in the second case, the compiler probably decides that [on the target architecture] simply issuing a fence is more efficient than checking what memory order you're using and then conditionally issuing a fence.

Comment: @Brian +1. mfence will probably go away if `my_order` will be declared static and non-const.

Comment: @Oleg That is a good point.. The compiler needs a compile time constant in order to take a decision on ordering and a non-static, non-const global may not qualify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule, when the compiler cannot prove that the ordering parameter is known at compile time, it will take no chance and assume worst-case.

In case `my_order` is a non-`const` global variable, the compiler cannot know what the actual value will be when the `store` is executed and therefore it is going to use `std::memory_order_seq_cst`.
If the variable is declared `const`, the ordering parameter will take effect and the `mfence` instruction is gone.